# Why does this textarea appear to only add one space instead of four?

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea

Here is my code:

```
doc.on("keydown", ".textarea_code_snippet", function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode === 9) { // tab was pressed

        // get caret position/selection
        var start = this.selectionStart;
        var end = this.selectionEnd;

        var $this = $(this);
        var value = $this.val();

        // set textarea value to: text before caret + tab + text
        // after caret 
        $this.val(value.substring(0, start)
                    + "\t"
                    + value.substring(end));

        // put caret at right position again (add one for the tab)
        this.selectionStart = this.selectionEnd = start + 1;

        // prevent the focus lose
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

It handles <kbd>Tab</kbd> key in the `<textarea>`. It appends `\t` to the textarea when you press the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key. Now I want to add 4 spaces instead. Here is my new version:

```
.
.
 $this.val(value.substring(0, start)
             + "    "
             + value.substring(end));
.
.
```

But it appends only *one* space to the textarea when I press <kbd>Tab</kbd>. How can I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried changing `this.selectionStart = this.selectionEnd = start + 1;` to `this.selectionStart = this.selectionEnd = start + 4;`?

Comment: It always appends 4 spaces for me...

Comment: I don't really understand the title of the question. The space symbol in JavaScript is the space...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *does* add four spaces. You just forgot to adjust one thing:

```
// put caret at right position again (add one for the tab)
this.selectionStart = this.selectionEnd = start + 1;
```

You probably see the caret move by only one space. You need to change the above lines to:

```
// Put caret at right position again (add four for four spaces)
this.selectionStart = this.selectionEnd = start + 4;
```

Comment: I tested what you said .. but still a tab (`\t`) appends when I press `tab` button

Comment: @MartinAJ You’re using your changed version that you’ve shown in the question, right? The one where you’re already using the four spaces instead of `"\t"`?

Comment: To make my question more clear, I want when you press `tab`, then you be able to press backspace 4 times.

Comment: @MartinAJ Yes, obviously if you still leave the `"\t"`, then you’ll get a `"\t"`. If you want four spaces, then use four spaces, as you’ve _already, correctly_ done in your question. That’s why I said _“you just forgot […]”_ in my post and not _“you did it wrong and should do this instead”_.